# How do I add & retrive nodes at level zero in treeview using c#

Tags: c#

how do i add & Retrieve Nodes at level zero in Treeview using c#
Following is the formate for Treeview:

```
-ALL
 +Node0
 +Node1
-Default
 +Node0
 +Node1
```

Please give your suggestion...
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The first example in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aspx) is not useful?

```
// Populates a TreeView control with example nodes.  
private void InitializeTreeView()
{
    treeView1.BeginUpdate();
    treeView1.Nodes.Add("Parent");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("Child 1");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("Child 2");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[1].Nodes.Add("Grandchild");
    treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[1].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("Great Grandchild");
    treeView1.EndUpdate();
}
```